# how to show red order when field is required in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could you please tell me how to show red order when field is required in angularjs .I prepare the form from `json` in which a field is coming **"required" : true**.so those field are required in my form . Now I want to show border  red if user not filled the fields

here is my code

```
 "First Name": {
    "value": "naveen",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": true,
    "dataType": "",
     "required":true
  },
  "Last Name": {
    "value": "",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": true,
    "dataType": "",
    "required":true
  }
```

So first name and last name is required

```
/* Put your css in here */

.error {
  corder: 1px solid red;
}
```

I want to add this class to field if there is an error of required on **button  click**
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/19nvRM1ZBQqADhYk1XTR?p=preview

can I show red border if form is not valid or invalid fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using a `form` element, you'll get the features provided by the [`form`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) directive provided by AngularJS. It's simply a matter of hooking up the validation.

Specifically, the HTML change required to get what you want:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myform[key].$invalid}">
    <input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-required="value.required">
</div>
```

A few points with the suggestion here:

- You appear to be using Bootstrap 3.3, in which case the framework already provides accessible error state validation styling (i.e. notice the `form-group has-error` combination). There's no need to define a separate red border CSS class, unless you really want to. [See here for more details.](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#callout-form-validation-state-accessibility)
- Each input field requiring validation should define the `name` attribute
- The validation state of each input field is available via the `form` controller (i.e. `myform`)

[Here's a forked version of your Plunker with the above suggestions.](http://plnkr.co/edit/fhBLAoMQiFn2wJKxxJtl?p=preview)

#### Edit

In response to the further commentary, the changes you'll need to do that:

- Move the submit button underneath the form element
- Apply `novalidate` on the form element to suppress native browser validation
- Extend the `ng-class` condition to involve the `$touched` and `$submitted` properties

[Updated Plunker fork.](http://plnkr.co/edit/X84nBxlyPeMJbew0wIS0?p=preview)

Comment: you are showing error on "when application run " I want same thing on button click not on load

Comment: can I show red border on button click will I use "pristine or dirty" property of form

Comment: Right—I'd missed that detail. Updated my answer.

Comment: sorry for late replay thanks for help ..can we check in javascript is form is valid or not like this "my form.valid()" or not ?

Comment: Provided `myform` is in scope of the controller you're accessing it from, yes, you can use the `myform.$valid` property. For a full list of properties, refer to the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController